# How do I get my pargraph to line up on top with my div container?

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I am making a skills bar, that I want to use for my website. But the text like html,css etc isn't lining up with my bars. (These aren't my real % am a beginner in html and css) Feel free to change anything that you think is necessary. Below is my html and css.

```css
.skills h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.container-skill {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.skill {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.skills p {
  margin: 0.1%;
}

.html {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.css {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.js {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.php {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.skill-box {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
  <h1>Skills</h1>
  <div class="skill-box">
    <p>HTML</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill html">90%</div>
    </div>

    <p>CSS</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill css">80%</div>
    </div>

    <p>JavaScript</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill js">65%</div>
    </div>

    <p>PHP</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill php">60%</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Feel free to change anything that you think is necessary. This just extra text as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of your paragraphs to 40% to match the divs, and change the margin to also match:

```css
.skills h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.container-skill {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.skill {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.skills p {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.html {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.css {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.js {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.php {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.skill-box {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
  <h1>Skills</h1>
  <div class="skill-box">
    <p>HTML</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill html">90%</div>
    </div>
    <p>CSS</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill css">80%</div>
    </div>
    <p>JavaScript</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill js">65%</div>
    </div>
    <p>PHP</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill php">60%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see what you did and it's margin is auto so it's even on both side right?

Comment: Yes. When you set the width of the element to 40% and the left/right margins to auto, it centers the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can *line them up* using `inline-block` *display* and *aligning* them *vertically* by using `vertical-align: middle` - add this to your CSS:

```
.skill-box > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0.1%;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
.skills h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.container-skill {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.skill {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.skills p {
  margin: 0.1%;
}

.html {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.css {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.js {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.php {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.skill-box {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.skill-box > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0.1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
  <h1>Skills</h1>
  <div class="skill-box">

    <p>HTML</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill html">90%</div>
    </div>

    <p>CSS</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill css">80%</div>
    </div>

    <p>JavaScript</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill js">65%</div>
    </div>

    <p>PHP</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill php">60%</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**EDIT**: If you want to have them one below the other, just remove `margin-left: auto` from `container-skill` to *push* it to the left or just add `text-align: center` to the `.skill-box p` for *aligning* everything to the center - see demo below:

```css
.skills h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.container-skill {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.skill-box p { /* ADDED THIS */
  text-align: center;
}

.skill {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.skills p {
  margin: 0.1%;
}

.html {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.css {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.js {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.php {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.skill-box {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
  <h1>Skills</h1>
  <div class="skill-box">

    <p>HTML</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill html">90%</div>
    </div>

    <p>CSS</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill css">80%</div>
    </div>

    <p>JavaScript</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill js">65%</div>
    </div>

    <p>PHP</p>
    <div class="container-skill">
      <div class="skill php">60%</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I will change my question title, is there a way for me to have the HTml, css and etc to be on top of there respected bars?

Comment: you mean one below the other?

Comment: Yes like have HTML be on the top of it's respected bar?